# Is it bad idea to put 64b application into ProgramFiles(x86)?

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit

We are shipping application, that is 32b, and, therefore, put into `ProgramFiles(x86)` directory. There is x64 'plugin' for it, running as a separate process (service), and now we're deploying it into the main application's subdirectory. The plugin isn't deployed on x86 systems.

Now, the question - isn't this (having x64 exectuable in x86 ProgramFiles) considered as bad idea? Can this solution have negative impact on *(something)*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has no negative impact, and in fact, Visual Studio also does this (it installs its 64-bit native compilers into the (x86) directories).

This is only problematic if it's a "real" 64-bit application that expects to be where it's supposed to be (wrt "Program Files"), as certain WinAPI functions that give you this directory work differently for 64-bit and 32-bit applications.

Answer (score 1):

For an x64 program, the %PROGRAMFILES% environmental variables and their analogues are pointing to the `Program Files` (no x86) directory. So there may be some problems with locating the files that were put in the wrong directory.
Since your app is 32bit, there shouldn't be any problems.